# Adding blank row to google spread sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have this simple python script that creates a google spread sheet for me from a CSV file.

```
import gspread
import csv
import time

# Authenticate using gspread.oauth()
gc = gspread.oauth()

# Open or create a new Google Sheets document
spreadsheet = gc.create('Your Spreadsheet Name')

# Read CSV data and add it to the spreadsheet
with open('your_csv_file.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        if not row:  # Check if the row is empty
            print(f"Adding blaknk row: {row}.")
            spreadsheet.sheet1.append_row(['    ', '   ', '    ', '    ', '    ', '    ', '    ', '    ', '    ', '    ', '    ', '    ', '    '])
        else:
            while True:
                try:
                    print(f"Adding row: {row}.")
                    spreadsheet.sheet1.append_row(row)
                    time.sleep(5)  # Add a sleep of 5 seconds between each append_row() call
                    break
                except gspread.exceptions.APIError as e:
                    if e.response.status_code == 503:
                        print("Service Unavailable. Retrying in 10 seconds ...")
                        time.sleep(10)  # Wait for 10 seconds before retrying
                    else:
                        raise e
```

The problem is that I do not see my "blank" row.  The csv file has a blank row for cosmetic purposes.

```
(venv) [red@BP22006 aws_cost_explorer]$ head -30 your_csv_file.csv
"Service Name   af-south-1","2023-03","2023-04","2023-05","2023-06","2023-07","2023-08","2023-09","2023-10","2023-11","2023-12","2024-01","2024-02"
"AWS VPC","0","0","0","0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","6.96"
"EBS Volumes gp2","19.63","19.64","19.63","19.64","19.63","19.63","19.64","19.63","19.64","19.63","19.63","19.64"
"EC2 - Other","27.59","27.79","27.14","27.26","27.64","26.4","26.55","27.79","29.6","28.91","33.82","25.15"
"EC2","94.14","76.91","59.53","57.61","59.53","59.53","57.61","59.53","57.61","64.88","60.07","56.52"
"PublicIPv4:IdleAddress","0","0","0","0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","3.48"
"PublicIPv4:InUseAddress","0","0","0","0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","3.48"
"Other          af-south-1","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","-0.0","-0.0","0.0","0.0","-6.96"
"TOTAL:         af-south-1","121.73","104.7","86.67","84.87","87.17","85.93","84.16","87.32","87.21","93.79","93.89","88.63"

"Service Name   ap-northeast-1","2023-03","2023-04","2023-05","2023-06","2023-07","2023-08","2023-09","2023-10","2023-11","2023-12","2024-01","2024-02"
"AWS Direct Connect","1575.24","1512.77","1629.79","1497.54","1504.33","1484.96","1543.41","1510.99","1404.84","1428.71","1424.15","1361.66"
"AWS ELB","76.29","75.02","80.48","79.06","71.27","72.74","74.61","77.1","72.42","78.28","73.62","73.42"
"AWS S3","51.77","53.71","52.56","53.83","55.7","53.57","54.26","55.99","55.97","56.97","56.75","56.94"
"AWS VPC","0","0","0","0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","48.73"
"EBS Volumes gp2","403.58","414.48","414.48","414.48","427.1","438.48","438.48","438.48","438.48","438.48","438.48","438.48"
"EBS Volumes gp3","206.21","206.21","206.21","206.21","206.21","206.21","206.21","206.21","207.42","208.13","208.13","208.13"
"EBS Volumes","491.52","491.52","491.52","491.52","491.52","491.52","491.52","491.52","491.52","491.52","491.52","491.52"
"EC2 - Other","1512.1","1502.28","1523.26","1513.06","1518.93","1523.01","1533.47","1525.14","1502.29","1503.11","1492.42","1485.31"
"EC2","1235.61","1159.1","1175.3","1151.3","1155.16","1141.6","1123.86","1160.83","1120.61","1481.42","1939.9","1320.95"
"PublicIPv4:InUseAddress","0","0","0","0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","48.73"
"Other          ap-northeast-1","0.0","0.0","-0.01","-0.01","0.01","0.0","-0.0","0.0","0.0","-0.0","0.0","-48.73"
"TOTAL:         ap-northeast-1","4451.01","4302.88","4461.38","4294.78","4305.4","4275.88","4329.61","4330.05","4156.13","4548.49","4986.84","4347.01"

"Service Name   ap-southeast-1","2023-03","2023-04","2023-05","2023-06","2023-07","2023-08","2023-09","2023-10","2023-11","2023-12","2024-01","2024-02"
"AWS CloudWatch","0.74","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0"
"AWS ELB","21.05","19.76","21.62","20.51","20.87","21.52","20.37","21.11","20.32","20.19","20.8","22.89"
"AWS S3","36.04","36.25","36.22","36.54","36.99","36.86","36.93","36.44","36.31","36.58","35.21","35.51"
"AWS VPC","0","0","0","0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","27.85"
"EBS Volumes gp2","50.88","50.88","50.88","50.88","50.88","50.88","50.88","50.88","50.88","50.88","51.65","52.8"
...
```

But when I go to google sheets I see that there is no blank row in the spreadsheet:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion: Use the `batch_update` method instead

The `append_row` method inserts data on the first non-empty row in the spreadsheet, which also overwrites the blank row added by the script. I suggest using the `batch_update` method to insert the entire CSV file, including the empty rows. This has the added benefit of only utilizing a single API call to insert the entire CSV file.

Do try this slightly modified version of your script:

```
import gspread
import csv
import time

# Authenticate using gspread.oauth()
gc = gspread.oauth()

# Open or create a new Google Sheets document
spreadsheet = gc.create('Your Spreadsheet Name')

data = []

# Read CSV data and add it to the spreadsheet
with open('your_csv_file.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        data.append(row)

#Gets the total rows of the CSV file
rowCount = len(data) 

#Gets the total columns of the CSV file, based on the first row.
columnCount = len(data[0])
try:
  #Calls the batch_update method and inserts the data from the CSV file to Google Sheets.
  spreadsheet.sheet1.batch_update([{
      'range': f'A1:{chr(columnCount+65)}{rowCount}',
      'values': data
  }])
  print("Data successfully uploaded to Google Sheets.")

except gspread.exceptions.APIError as e:
  if e.response.status_code == 503:
      print("Service Unavailable. Retrying in 10 seconds ...")
      time.sleep(10)  # Wait for 10 seconds before retrying
  else:
      raise e
```

Here's how the data shows up on my end after inserting the CSV file via `batch_update`:
[image]

### EDIT:

It's possible to modify the background color after the data is inserted to Google Sheets. This script, for example, modifies the background color of all cells containing `AWS VPC`:

```
service_name = spreadsheet.sheet1.findall('AWS VPC')
for cell in service_name:
  spreadsheet.sheet1.format(
    f'A{cell.row}', {
    "backgroundColor": {
      "red": 0.0,
      "green": 0.0,
      "blue": 50.0
    },
  })
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a good suggestion.  I will be adding formatting. E.G. Making all the cost cells US Dollar formatted and changing the background color based on the "Service Name".  Will I still be able to update the formatting?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it is possible to update the background color after the data from the CSV file is inserted to Google Sheets. I've updated the answer and included an example of how a cell's background color can be updated based on the service name. I assume that changing the cell's formatting is possible via the same method as well. However, please note that you might hit the API limits depending on how large the inserted data is.